# Block Youtube ads

Tags: regex, pihole

I'm trying to block the annoying youtube ads with pihole but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The following is not viewed at all:

```
(rr[\d]{1}---[\s]{2}-[\s]{8}-[\w]{4})\.googlevideo\.com
```

Has anyone had similar experiences?

Examples look like this

```
rr1---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhl.googlevideo.com
rr1---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhl.googlevideo.com
rr3---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhz.googlevideo.com
rr6---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhl.googlevideo.com
```

Comment: Do you have some examples that it should and should not match?

Comment: What are the rules, in English, for what should match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird if an advertisement is played the following is displayed in the query log (examples only):

rr1---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhl.googlevideo.com or rr1---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhl.googlevideo.com or rr3---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhz.googlevideo.com or rr6---sn-8xgn5uxa-quhl.googlevideo.com

I try to block this using the regex

Comment: @allstar_141 Can you add those examples to the question? I think this pattern will match those examples `rr\d---sn-[a-z0-9]{8}-\w{4}\.googlevideo\.com` https://regex101.com/r/RfGRId/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have added the examples
on regex101.com everything works without no problems only in pihole unfortunately not

Comment: @allstar_141 Try it like this `rr[[:digit:]]---sn-[[:alnum:]]{8}-[[:alnum:]]{4}\.googlevideo\.com` https://regex101.com/r/5sCtKz/1

Comment: `\s` is a meta-escape for whitespace, not literal "s".

Comment: @Thefourthbird I'll try that and get right back to you. Thanks already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pi-Hole documentation](https://docs.pi-hole.net/regex/tutorial/) does not mention the usual abbrevations for character classes (like `\d`, `\s` or `\w` you used).

If you replace your character classes with the ones from the Pi-Hole documentation you end with

```
(rr[:digit:]{1}---[:space:]{2}-[:space:]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9_]{4})\.googlevideo\.com
```

Probably the `\s` is not what you originally wanted, as your examples contain letters there instead of spaces. And `\w` includes an underscore, that does not appear in your examples. Also a `{1}` can be skipped.

So I would suggest this expression:

```
(rr[:digit:]---[:alnum:]{2}-[:alnum:]{8}-[:alnum:]{4})\.googlevideo\.com
```

If you don't need the hostname-part for further processing, you could remove the group marker `()` around it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `[\s]{2}` in the pattern (which can be written as `\s{2}` matches 2 whitespace chars, but in the example data there is `sn`

The single meta characters in this case do not have to be placed between square brackets.

Looking at some documentation [on this page](https://docs.pi-hole.net/regex/tutorial/) `\w` `\s` and `\d` are not supported.

You might use

```
rr[[:digit:]]---sn-[[:alnum:]]{8}-[[:alnum:]]{4}\.googlevideo\.com
```

The pattern matches:

- `rr[[:digit:]]` Match `rr` and a single digit
- `---sn-` Match literally
- `[[:alnum:]]{8}` Match 8 alphanumerics
- `-[[:alnum:]]{4}` Match `-` and 4 alphanumerics
- `\.googlevideo\.com` Match `.googlevideo.com`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RfGRId/1).

Answer (score 0):

This pattern matches all your samples but it may be too tight?

```
rr\d---sn-8xgn5uxa-quh\w.googlevideo.com
```